# Fancy URL PHP and Flex

Tags: php, html, apache-flex

I have added an swf in my php page using `embed` and `object` of HTML.It loads the SWF in `http://localhost/swf.php?action=edit` and working fine, but when i apply url rewriting then the swf is not shown on the page although `$_REQUEST['action']` prints `edit` .The URL i am using is `http://localhost/swf/edit`

Any idea ??

Comment: Inside that page, how did you used the link to your SWF file ? I think, that link is being prevented because of the url rewriting. Have a look at it.

Comment: `<embed src="flash/test.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"....... ></embed>`

Answer (score 0):

The SWF file is not being shown because, according to your example embed, the site will be looking for the SWF file at /swf/edit/flash/test.swf.

I had the same problem with one of my systems when i first started using the single point of entry ideas.

I fixed our problem by using the  tag in the HTML and then making sure that all of the paths built themselves relative to this.

A quick fix to see if this is correct is to change the path of the SWF embed to ../../flash/test.swf - if it loads then you know that its the URL rewrite on the path thats the issue :)

Comment: I think thats not the issue because if i use it with `http://localhost/flash/...` it still does'nt work

Comment: I think the problem is in `AC_OETags.js`, but cant find the problem.Firebug says no object initiated in the js file.it  does not throw any error using complete URL

Comment: Could you post the code? If there is a js error then I *may* be able to help track it down!

Just out of interest - does it load if the full path is used

`http://localhost/flash/test.swf`

Another question is this: What server is it running on, and if the answer is Apache then please post your HTAccess file so that I can check your rewrite rules - I'll try to help as much as I can!